# Making complex folds in MySQL dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

This is really multiple questions in one, I apologize for the question overload, but I just need these done elegantly. I can handle my way around simple queries in MySQL but those complex tabulations usually befundle me quite well and I'm not yet familiar with dynamic SQL. Looking for simple solutions (but not hard coded):. I'm not sure if this is too much to ask in a Question on SO, if it is indeed too much, please answer one or two of the aggregations and give me the tools so I can build these kinds of aggregations myself.

My data is structured as follows:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  timestamp           group   url         metric columns here    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 6732    abc.com     -0.3673 -0.0914 4.0183  |
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 6732    xyz.com      4.2187  0.3407 12.3832 |
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 6732    pqr.org     -2.3875 -0.4064 5.8743  |
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 6732    many.com    -4.4194 -1.0665 4.144   |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 7174    abc.com     -6.4021 -1.419  4.5117  |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 7174    xyz.com     -1.7971 -1.0396 1.7286  |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 7174    many.com     0.5276  0.2621 2.013   |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 7174    many.com    -0.4941 -0.1098 4.4982  |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 7184    diff.com    -0.6783 -0.1384 4.9013  |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 7184    sites.com   -0.1293 -0.0246 5.2608  |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 7184    here.com    -0.2703 -0.0669 4.0377  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically, for each timestamps, we have data from different groups, and for each group we have urls, for each urls we have metrics being captured. Urls and adgroups have many to many relationship.

I have to pull and aggregate this data in multiple ways as per case demands. Usually, I select whatever metrics I need and group by one or many of timestamp, group, and url. However, sometimes I want to see data/aggregation within a group, but I end up running a seperate query for them. For instance, aggregating by time I see at a particular time-window, a certain metric has dropped or shot up, and I want to dig into each time window seperately and I'll have to repeat this seperately because within a timewindow, certain groups can go up and down and digging into them to get the url stage needs a seperate query. What I need is a way to aggregate at top levels- timestamps, and groups but also show aggregation from below levels. An example:

Something like this would really help:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|      timestamp      | aggregate_1 | aggregate_2 | window_top_group | window_top_group_aggregate_1 | window_top_group_aggregate_2 | window_top_group_2 | window_top_group_2_aggregate_1 | window_top_group_2_aggregate_2 | window_loss_group_1 | window_loss_group_1_aggregate_1 | window_loss_group_1_aggregate_2 |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 | -0.3673     | -0.0914     |             6732 | -0.3673                      | -0.3673                      |               7174 | -0.3673                        | -0.3673                        |                7184 | -0.3673                         | -0.3673                         |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 | 4.2187      | 0.3407      |             6732 | 4.2187                       | 4.2187                       |               7174 | 4.2187                         | 4.2187                         |                7184 | 4.2187                          | 4.2187                          |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 | -2.3875     | -0.4064     |             6732 | -2.3875                      | -2.3875                      |               7174 | -2.3875                        | -2.3875                        |                7184 | -2.3875                         | -2.3875                         |
| 2018-05-01 13:00:00 | -4.4194     | -1.0665     |             6732 | -4.4194                      | -4.4194                      |               7174 | -4.4194                        | -4.4194                        |                7184 | -4.4194                         | -4.4194                         |
| 2018-05-01 12:30:00 | -6.4021     | -1.419      |             7174 | -6.4021                      | -6.4021                      |               7184 | -6.4021                        | -6.4021                        |                6732 | -6.4021                         | -6.4021                         |
| 2018-05-01 12:00:00 | -1.7971     | -1.0396     |             7174 | -1.7971                      | -1.7971                      |               7184 | -1.7971                        | -1.7971                        |                6732 | -1.7971                         | -1.7971                         |
| 2018-05-01 11:30:00 | 0.5276      | 0.2621      |             7174 | 0.5276                       | 0.5276                       |               7184 | 0.5276                         | 0.5276                         |                6732 | 0.5276                          | 0.5276                          |
| 2018-05-01 11:00:00 | -0.4941     | -0.1098     |             7174 | -0.4941                      | -0.4941                      |               6732 | -0.4941                        | -0.4941                        |                7184 | -0.4941                         | -0.4941                         |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | -0.6783     | -0.1384     |             7184 | -0.6783                      | -0.6783                      |               6732 | -0.6783                        | -0.6783                        |                7174 | -0.6783                         | -0.6783                         |
| 2018-05-01 10:00:00 | -0.1293     | -0.0246     |             7184 | -0.1293                      | -0.1293                      |               6732 | -0.1293                        | -0.1293                        |                7174 | -0.1293                         | -0.1293                         |
| 2018-05-01 9:30:00  | -0.2703     | -0.0669     |             7184 | -0.2703                      | -0.2703                      |               6732 | -0.2703                        | -0.2703                        |                7174 | -0.2703                         | -0.2703                         |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Perhaps could we even go one level deeper? and say while aggregating timestamps, get top urls for the top groups or perhaps top group-url combos?

Few other aggregations that would really help:

1) Say for a particular range in time, say a full month:
Aggregated by urls, showing best/worst times & values for the whole range, but also average them across time of day over the full month and pick up aggregates there, as shown:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
|    url    | aggregate_1 | aggregate_2 | best performance timestamp overall | worst performance timestamp overall | peak time of average day | trough time of average day | mean_at_peak | standard_deviation_at_peak | mean_at_trough | standard_deviation_at_trough |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
| abc.com   | -0.3673     | -0.3673     | 2018-05-01 14:30:00                | 2018-05-01 14:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 9:30:00       | 2018-05-01 9:30:00         | 0.5276       | 0.5276                     | 0.5276         | 0.5276                       |
| xyz.com   | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 2018-05-01 14:00:00                | 2018-05-01 14:00:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:00:00      | 2018-05-01 10:00:00        | 0.5276       | 0.5276                     | 0.5276         | 0.5276                       |
| pqr.org   | -2.3875     | -2.3875     | 2018-05-01 13:30:00                | 2018-05-01 13:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:30:00      | 2018-05-01 10:30:00        | 4.2187       | 4.2187                     | 4.2187         | 4.2187                       |
| many.com  | -4.4194     | -4.4194     | 2018-05-01 13:00:00                | 2018-05-01 13:00:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:30:00      | 2018-05-01 10:30:00        | 5.449066667  | 5.449066667                | 5.449066667    | 5.449066667                  |
| abc.com   | -6.4021     | -6.4021     | 2018-05-01 12:30:00                | 2018-05-01 10:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 12:00:00      | 2018-05-01 12:00:00        | 4.2187       | 4.2187                     | 4.2187         | 4.2187                       |
| xyz.com   | -1.7971     | -1.7971     | 2018-05-01 12:00:00                | 2018-05-01 12:00:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:30:00      | 2018-05-01 10:30:00        | 0.5276       | 0.5276                     | 0.5276         | 0.5276                       |
| pqr.org   | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 2018-05-01 11:30:00                | 2018-05-01 10:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:30:00      | 2018-05-01 10:30:00        | 7.985716667  | 7.985716667                | 7.985716667    | 7.985716667                  |
| many.com  | -0.4941     | -0.4941     | 2018-05-01 11:00:00                | 2018-05-01 11:00:00                 | 2018-05-01 11:00:00      | 2018-05-01 11:00:00        | 4.2187       | 4.2187                     | 4.2187         | 4.2187                       |
| many.com  | -0.6783     | -0.6783     | 2018-05-01 10:30:00                | 2018-05-01 10:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 9:30:00       | 2018-05-01 9:30:00         | 0.5276       | 0.5276                     | 0.5276         | 0.5276                       |
| sites.com | -0.1293     | -0.1293     | 2018-05-01 10:00:00                | 2018-05-01 10:00:00                 | 2018-05-01 10:30:00      | 2018-05-01 10:30:00        | 9.522366667  | 9.522366667                | 9.522366667    | 9.522366667                  |
| here.com  | -0.2703     | -0.2703     | 2018-05-01 9:30:00                 | 2018-05-01 9:30:00                  | 2018-05-01 10:00:00      | 2018-05-01 10:00:00        | 4.2187       | 4.2187                     | 4.2187         | 4.2187                       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+------------------------------+
```

2) Either for a list of specified urls or have the query itself build the list of urls, for example those that match a pattern or the top 3 using metric_1 from in each window, show a percentage contribution for supplied or desired metrics:

```
+---------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|      timestamp      | metric_1 | contribution_percentage_url_1 | contribution_percentage_url_2 | contribution_percentage_url_3 | metric_2 | contribution_percentage_url_1 | contribution_percentage_url_2 | contribution_percentage_url_3 |
+---------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 | -0.3673  |                            33 |                            26 |                            18 | -0.3673  |                            53 |                            30 |                            11 |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 | 4.2187   |                            33 |                            29 |                            12 | 4.2187   |                            30 |                            32 |                            20 |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 | -2.3875  |                            53 |                            29 |                            17 | -2.3875  |                            37 |                            32 |                            11 |
| 2018-05-01 13:00:00 | -4.4194  |                            39 |                            27 |                            19 | -4.4194  |                            31 |                            34 |                            10 |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | -6.4021  |                            41 |                            25 |                            15 | -6.4021  |                            31 |                            30 |                            16 |
| 2018-05-01 12:00:00 | -1.7971  |                            45 |                            27 |                            12 | -1.7971  |                            32 |                            30 |                            12 |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | 0.5276   |                            50 |                            35 |                            18 | 0.5276   |                            41 |                            25 |                            13 |
| 2018-05-01 11:00:00 | -0.4941  |                            33 |                            33 |                            16 | -0.4941  |                            44 |                            34 |                            13 |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | -0.6783  |                            53 |                            33 |                            18 | -0.6783  |                            54 |                            33 |                            16 |
| 2018-05-01 10:00:00 | -0.1293  |                            38 |                            31 |                            14 | -0.1293  |                            42 |                            31 |                            17 |
| 2018-05-01 9:30:00  | -0.2703  |                            30 |                            35 |                            11 | -0.2703  |                            30 |                            35 |                            16 |
+---------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

3) Pivoting:
for a supplied list of dates or +- 5 days from a supplied date and a particular key measure: compare the measure across the days:

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| time of day | date-5  |   date-4    |   date-3    |   date-2    |   date-1    |  date   |   date+1    |   date+2    |   date+3    |   date+4    | date+5  |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| 14:30:00    | -0.3673 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -0.3673 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -0.3673 |
| 14:00:00    | 4.2187  | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 4.2187  | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 4.2187  |
| 13:30:00    | -2.3875 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -2.3875 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -2.3875 |
| 13:00:00    | -4.4194 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | -4.4194 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | 5.449066667 | -4.4194 |
| 12:30:00    | -6.4021 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -6.4021 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -6.4021 |
| 12:00:00    | -1.7971 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -1.7971 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -1.7971 |
| 11:30:00    | 0.5276  | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 0.5276  | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 7.985716667 | 0.5276  |
| 11:00:00    | -0.4941 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -0.4941 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -0.4941 |
| 10:30:00    | -0.6783 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -0.6783 | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | 0.5276      | -0.6783 |
| 10:00:00    | -0.1293 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | -0.1293 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | 9.522366667 | -0.1293 |
| 9:30:00     | -0.2703 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -0.2703 | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | 4.2187      | -0.2703 |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

4) There is a metric called metric_lg which denotes the lifespan or lifecycle of a url based on its count. So lets say from a specified date or the first timestamp of a group, calculate certain metric aggregates based on its count, i.e., for a single url, the ranges would be 1-5, 5-10, 10-20, 20-50, 50-80, 80-200, 200-1000, 1000-10000, 10000+: lets call them stages A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I. The thing however is that this count needs to be cumulated, ie., from its appearance in the group from the time the group started. Lets say a group 7184 was started in 2018-05-01 10:00:00, and 7174 was started at 2018-04-30 12:00:00, then a particular url appearing in both groups would have its metric_lg cumulated from the start of the respective group i.e., its lifecycle stage in 7184 would be a cumulation of metric_lg from the start of 7184 ie., 2018-05-01 10:00:00 and its life cycle stage in 7174 would be a cumulation of metric_lg from start of 7174 ie., 2018-04-30 12:00:00.

So for a supplied list of groups, something like this will help: calculate someother metric aggregate based on its metric_lg life cycle stages and compare group performance broken by life cycle stages.

```
+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      timestamp      | A_aggregate_metric | B _aggregate_metric | C_aggregate_metric | D_aggregate_metric | E_aggregate_metric | F_aggregate_metric | G_aggregate_metric | H_aggregate_metric | I_aggregate_metric |
+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2018-05-01 14:30:00 | -0.3673            | 0.5276              | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | -0.3673            | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             |
| 2018-05-01 14:00:00 | 4.2187             | 0.5276              | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 4.2187             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             |
| 2018-05-01 13:30:00 | -2.3875            | 4.2187              | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | -2.3875            | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             |
| 2018-05-01 13:00:00 | -4.4194            | 5.449066667         | 5.449066667        | 5.449066667        | 5.449066667        | -4.4194            | 5.449066667        | 5.449066667        | 5.449066667        |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | -6.4021            | 4.2187              | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | -6.4021            | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             |
| 2018-05-01 12:00:00 | -1.7971            | 0.5276              | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | -1.7971            | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | 0.5276             | 7.985716667         | 7.985716667        | 7.985716667        | 7.985716667        | 0.5276             | 7.985716667        | 7.985716667        | 7.985716667        |
| 2018-05-01 11:00:00 | -0.4941            | 4.2187              | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | -0.4941            | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             |
| 2018-05-01 10:30:00 | -0.6783            | 0.5276              | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | -0.6783            | 0.5276             | 0.5276             | 0.5276             |
| 2018-05-01 10:00:00 | -0.1293            | 9.522366667         | 9.522366667        | 9.522366667        | 9.522366667        | -0.1293            | 9.522366667        | 9.522366667        | 9.522366667        |
| 2018-05-01 9:30:00  | -0.2703            | 4.2187              | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | -0.2703            | 4.2187             | 4.2187             | 4.2187             |
+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

If you need data context, assume, three metrics: 
metric_1: revenue in dollars
metric_2: cost in dollars
metric_lg:traffic count in thousands

PS: doing this is MySQL over python is preferable because some of this will go into creating custom VIEWs so they can be frequently looked at and done further analysis on.

This is a lot, thanks a lot, really

Comment: For what it's worth, the sort of user-driven analytic displays and drill-downs you want are hard to do in pre-defined views. And, pivots are truly unpleasant in MySQL. You rightly observe that you have a lot of different types of display to deliver. Ordinarily this sort of thing is done by a program (python in your case) that uses string concatenation to build appropriate queries, then runs them, then formats the result (into HTML tables or whatever form you need). I suppose that's what you mean by "dynamic sql".

Comment: No, what I meant by Dynamic SQLs are queries in themselves where variables, for loops, if conditions, etc are written, sort of bring mainstream programming to SQL- I haven't really ventured beyond static SQL. I've tried doing this in Python, but I really want an SQL solution so that I can build and keep views, and have certain triggers also put in place. That sort of thing.

Comment: For what its worth, I'll post solutions here when I crack something, but I just would end up spending a lot of time from scratch. I assumed learning off of someones query that already solves one or two of these  will help me get started and get off the ground quicker- a sort of practical approach

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I don't think you will find much in SQL to meet your goal. Why not? it's declarative by nature, not procedural. And, you cannot use variables to name tables or columns in queries. "Mainstream programming" is procedural. You could try to use MySQL's internal form of prepared statements, which is like SQL Server's `sp_execute` operation, to build your SQL queries in your own stored procedures using string concatenation, then run them. But stored procedures are much harder to debug than python code.

Comment: @O.Jones, one of the main purpose of dynamic SQL is to enable programmers to phrase queries on-the-flight. I guess what Deepak needs is a (most probably very complex) logic to build queries based on the received criteria, and then execute them.